# Number 401002, Severity 2Restoring Sybase 12.5.2 backup

Tags: sybase, restore

I was able to recover one ASE 12.5.2 backup file from a malware attack serve [.bk]. I created similar Device sizes and database and try to load to a new server I am getting below error. I tried with few backup files and still the same. These backup files are Not Compressed.
Tried with different servers and results is same. Can anyone help me here to over come this and restore this backup. Or does anyone know a way to repair a Sybase 12.5.2 backup file?

```
-------
Server Message:  Number  3216, Severity  10
Server 'GF2TEST', Line 1:
Backup Server session id is:  7.  Use this value when executing the 'sp_volchanged' system stored procedure after fulfilling any volume change request from the Backup Server. 
Server Message:  Number  401002, Severity  2
Server 'GF2TEST_BS', Procedure 'bs_read_header', Line 0:
Backup Server: 4.10.2.1: Label validation error: first label not VOL1. 
Server Message:  Number  603102, Severity  2
Server 'GF2TEST_BS', Procedure 'bs_read_header', Line 0:
Backup Server: 6.31.2.4: Volume rejected. 
Server Message:  Number  101402, Severity  2
Server 'GF2TEST_BS', Procedure 'bs_read_header', Line 0:
Backup Server: 1.14.2.2: Unrecoverable I/O or volume error.  This DUMP or         LOAD session must exit. 
Server Message:  Number  603202, Severity  2
Server 'GF2TEST_BS', Procedure 'bs_read_header', Line 0:
Backup Server: 6.32.2.3: C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\GF2 Backup\GF225012015.bk: volume not valid or not requested (server: , session id: 7.) 
Server Message:  Number  101402, Severity  2
Server 'GF2TEST_BS', Procedure 'bs_read_header', Line 0:
Backup Server: 1.14.2.4: Unrecoverable I/O or volume error.  This DUMP or     LOAD session must exit. 
Server Message:  Number  8009, Severity  16
Server 'GF2TEST', Line 1:
Error encountered by Backup Server.  Please refer to Backup Server messages for details.
```

Comment: This might be better suited to ServerFault rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DavidMaust This is a DBA question more than a SA question, so I would suggest dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you sure there is only 1 backup file?  There error is telling you that the file you are giving it is not labled Vol1.  I suggest you check your backup files with the `load database db_name from '/path/db_name.dmp' with headeronly` - this will print out the header information from your backup files without trying to actually restore the backup.